# Plot a line that connects the outer points of a plot

Tags: r

I would like to plot a line that connects the outer points of the plot

```
plot(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000), xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))
```

and thus "bags" all points of the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function to be used here is `chull`. Line 4 is there to close the circle. For more examples, see [here](http://chitchatr.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/convex-hull-around-scatter-plot-in-r/).

```
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
plot(x)
chx <- chull(x)
chx <- rbind(x = x[chx, ], x[chx[1], ])
lines(chx)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It would be nice though if you could add the answer so that it exists in stackexchange. In cases anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 2):

```
a  <-  rnorm(1000)
b  <-  rnorm(1000)


Plot_ConvexHull<-function(xcoord, ycoord, lcolor){
hpts <- chull(x = xcoord, y = ycoord)
hpts <- c(hpts, hpts[1])
lines(xcoord[hpts], ycoord[hpts], col = lcolor)
}

(xrange <- range(c(a)))
(yrange <- range(c(b)))

par(tck = 0.02, mgp = c(1.7, 0.3, 0))
plot(a, b, type = "p", pch = 1, col = "black", xlim = c(xrange), ylim = c(yrange))
Plot_ConvexHull(xcoord = a, ycoord = b, lcolor = "black")
```